# "To" vs "As" vs "Get" Method Prefixes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Does anyone know of any naming convention rules/guidelines that dictate when to use a "To" prefix (`myVariable.ToList()`), an "As" prefix (`myVariable.AsEnumerable()`), or a "Get" prefix (`myVariable.GetHashCode()`)?

Comment: Just use what fits best to what you're doing. "To" creates something new, "As" is just a "different view" on the same and "Get" is a getter for everything else.

Comment: it is completely relevant to what will a method do in the program logic.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Very clear and to the point. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume there's no convention, so just use what fits best to what you're doing.

- "To" creates something new/ converts it
- "As" is just a "different view" on the same f.e. by using [`iterators`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx)
- "Get" is a getter for everything else

Comment: +1, There's also `has` and `is`, for when you would return a `boolean`

Comment: +1, concise and to the point. Makes my wordy answer obsolete. :-)

Comment: @Izkata: I think that's more of a Java convention. In .NET, you see `myControl.Enabled` much more often than `myControl.IsEnabled`.

Comment: @Heinzi Aha, I skimmed right over the tags.  But I do agree with your comment; when it's not a method call, that makes sense.  Given the examples in the question, I was thinking along the lines of `myControl.hasAccess(foo)` or `myControl.isAccessible()`.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding/conventions:

"To" performs a conversion; A new object is created in memory, based on the data inherent in your source.

"As" performs a cast; The same reference passed in is returned behind the "mask" of a different type.

"Get" performs pretty much anything else that takes in a source and whose primary product is a transformed result. Gets can perform a calculation, return a child, retrieve data from a store, instantiate objects from a default state, etc. Not all such methods have to be named "Get", but most methods intended to calculate, instantiate, project, or otherwise transform, and then return the product as their primary purpose are "getters".

Comment: This seems to be a more general, in my opinion better, answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. When `myObj` is not related to `List`, prefix "To" to convert.
2. When `myObj` is a subclass of `Enumerable`, prefix "As" to give it as Enumerable
3. When `myObj` is not related to `List`, but it composes / can compose `List` use "Get" prefix

Comment: With your explanation it is not clear why to use `To` and not `Get`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework for CRUD operations on a database, then using .ToList() will have your query be executed right there, as opposed to using AsEnumerable() which will use deferred execution until you actually try to access a record.

That's one that I thought of right off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

`As` is a reinterpretation of existing data. `AsEnumerable` does nothing. It is implemented as `return input;`.

`To` implies a conversion.

`Get` does not imply any of the former.

You *will* find valid deviations from these rules. They are not set in stone.

Comment: `AsEnumerable ` does only return itself in `Enumerable`, for example in `DataTableExtensions` it does plenty of things.

Comment: Sure, it was meant as an example. Probably that part dragged the whole answer down to unlikableness.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that `To` vs `As` has more to do with differences like `class` vs `interface`

i e you are saying `AsEnumerable` when you really want to return something that implements interface.

`ToList` on opposite returns new object which is representation of current state of current object, ie `ToDictionary` just another way of representing same data.

Third ones `Get` methods returns some properties of the object OR something about part of it's state and not the full state.